# Filter with addition or subtraction condition

Tags: java, jsonpath

I have a simple json payload. I would like to add a filter condition on this which checks if (mode == 'custom' and lastUpdatedDate - createdDate >= 180000).

Can someone help with the filter condition.

```
{
   "id":"1664437560",
   "mode":"CUSTOM",
   "createdDate":1664437561000,
   "lastUpdatedDate":1664437620256,
   "customerIdentifier":"8a9fcc828",
   "status":"Success"
}
```

p.s -- I am familiar with jsonpath but, could not find a way to have a filter condition with +/-/* operators. I also tried to add filter condition on sum function,which also didn't work.

Comment: You cant do calculation with JSONPath. This is a query language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library *Josson* can do the job.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "   \"id\":\"1664437560\"," +
    "   \"mode\":\"CUSTOM\"," +
    "   \"createdDate\":1664437561000," +
    "   \"lastUpdatedDate\":1664437620256," +
    "   \"customerIdentifier\":\"8a9fcc828\"," +
    "   \"status\":\"Success\"" +
    "}");
```

Query

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("[mode='CUSTOM' & calc(lastUpdatedDate - createdDate) >= 180000]");
System.out.println(node == null ? null : node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
null
```

Deserialization (Changed `lastUpdatedDate` to `1664437861000`)

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "   \"id\":\"1664437560\"," +
    "   \"mode\":\"CUSTOM\"," +
    "   \"createdDate\":1664437561000," +
    "   \"lastUpdatedDate\":1664437861000," +
    "   \"customerIdentifier\":\"8a9fcc828\"," +
    "   \"status\":\"Success\"" +
    "}");
```

Query

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("[mode='CUSTOM' & calc(lastUpdatedDate - createdDate) >= 180000]");
System.out.println(node == null ? null : node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "id" : "1664437560",
  "mode" : "CUSTOM",
  "createdDate" : 1664437561000,
  "lastUpdatedDate" : 1664437861000,
  "customerIdentifier" : "8a9fcc828",
  "status" : "Success"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have a follow up question on that. How can I filter the json for this condition: [createdDate > today's Date]. Is there support in Josson for that (also can I convert long to date and vice-versa)? I looked in the documentation but could not find it.

Comment: `josson.getNode(String.format("[createdDate > %d]", ZonedDateTime.now().toEpochSecond() * 1000))`